# Finding newlines in C++

Tags: c++

So, I've always wondered. How would you go to find a newline in C++?

I know you can find a character within a string like this:

```
if (strchr(str.c_str(), 'a')) {
    cout << "FOUND IT!";
}
```

But, how would you go finding a newline like this?:

```
this is a test[x]
the test is real[x]
keep testing it[x]
```

So where the [x] are located is where the new line is (assuming the [x] isn't there).

Comment: What is wrong with `strchr(str.c_str(), '\n')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the newline is an special character. The code is '\n', so you should have no problem finding the newline special character. How are you obtaining the strings? If you get them from a file there are functions that return the string with and without the new line character included.